# Investigating the Impact of Distance over Time: Comparing Estimates within Year Using a Linear Mixed Model Regression

Tags: r, regression, lme4

I need help in defining the reference group for my linear mixed model regression. My goal is to investigate the impact of distance over time, so I manually created an interaction term between the year and qun (year_qun). I'm interested in comparing my estimates within each year, where the low exposure group would serve as the reference group. For instance, in the year 2001, the reference group would be yr_qun2001_low, and I would obtain estimates for yr_qun2001_medium and yr_qun2001_high. Similarly, for 2002, the reference group would be yr_qun2002_low, and I would obtain estimates for yr_qun2002_medium and yr_qun2002_high, and so on.

```r
library(lme4)       # linear mixed-effects models
library(lmerTest)   # test for linear mixed-effects models
library(gtsummary)
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)

m1 <- lmer(distance ~ yr_qun + (1 | id), data = trajectories)

summary(m1)
```

Any help much appreciated!

[image]

here is my dummy data

```
dput(trajectories)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), distance = c(15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 
21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 
20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 
20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 
21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 21, 
20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 
25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 
15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 
23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 
24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 
24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 
23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 
24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 
24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 
23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24), age = c(8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L), sex = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
    2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
    2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
    2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
    2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
    2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
    2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
    2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
    2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
    2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, NA, 
    NA, NA, 2008L, 2009L, NA, NA, NA, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
    2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, NA, NA, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
    2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, NA, NA, 2003L, 2004L, 
    2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, NA, NA, 2003L, 
    2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, NA, NA, 
    2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, NA, 
    NA, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
    NA, NA, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
    2010L, NA, NA, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
    2009L, 2010L), qun = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), levels = c("", 
    "high", "low", "medium"), class = "factor"), yr_qun = structure(c(2L, 
    6L, 10L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 20L, 24L, 26L, 29L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 
    14L, 19L, 22L, 23L, 28L, 31L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 21L, 
    23L, 27L, 29L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 17L, 22L, 24L, 26L, 
    31L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 24L, 27L, 30L, 4L, 5L, 
    10L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 15L, 17L, 21L, 25L, 
    27L, 29L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 20L, 25L, 28L, 30L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 
    12L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 29L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 
    19L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 29L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 23L, 
    27L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 29L, 
    1L, 1L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 29L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 
    12L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 29L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 
    19L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 29L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 
    23L, 27L, 29L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 
    29L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 29L, 1L, 
    1L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 29L), levels = c("", 
    "2001_high", "2001_low", "2001_medium", "2002_high", "2002_low", 
    "2002_medium", "2003_high", "2003_low", "2003_medium", "2004_high", 
    "2004_low", "2004_medium", "2005_high", "2005_low", "2005_medium", 
    "2006_high", "2006_low", "2006_medium", "2007_high", "2007_low", 
    "2007_medium", "2008_high", "2008_low", "2008_medium", "2009_high", 
    "2009_low", "2009_medium", "2010_high", "2010_low", "2010_medium"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-183L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you model the interaction explicitly:

```
m1 <- lmer(distance ~ factor(year):qun + (1 | id), data = trajectories)
```

then we can define contrasts like so:

```
library(emmeans)
em <- emmeans(m1, ~ qun | year)
contrast(em, method = 'trt.vs.ctrl', ref = 'low')
```

Gives:

> ```
> year = 2001:
>  contrast     estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
>  high - low    6.0e-01 0.576 Inf   1.041  0.4783
>  medium - low  3.6e+00 0.503 Inf   7.157  <.0001
>
> year = 2002:
>  contrast     estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
>  high - low   -2.6e-05 0.552 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>  medium - low -4.2e-05 0.736 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>
> year = 2003:
>  contrast     estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
>  high - low    3.0e-06 0.689 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>  medium - low  2.3e-05 0.523 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>
> year = 2004:
>  contrast     estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
>  high - low   -2.5e-05 0.445 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>  medium - low  4.0e-06 0.445 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>
> year = 2005:
>  contrast     estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
>  high - low   -2.1e-05 0.398 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>  medium - low -6.0e-06 0.717 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>
> year = 2006:
>  contrast     estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
>  high - low    0.0e+00 0.562 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>  medium - low  1.0e-06 0.449 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>
> year = 2007:
>  contrast     estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
>  high - low    2.0e-05 0.523 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>  medium - low  0.0e+00 0.689 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>
> year = 2008:
>  contrast     estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
>  high - low    0.0e+00 0.441 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>  medium - low  0.0e+00 0.629 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>
> year = 2009:
>  contrast     estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
>  high - low    1.3e-05 0.521 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>  medium - low -1.7e-05 0.521 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>
> year = 2010:
>  contrast     estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
>  high - low    1.7e-05 0.523 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>  medium - low -3.0e-06 0.689 Inf   0.000  1.0000
>
> Degrees-of-freedom method: asymptotic 
> P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 2 tests
> ```

Note that we are only adjusting p-values for multiple testing within each year.

You can plot the means (with their confidence intervals) as well:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(as.data.frame(em), aes(year, emmean, color = qun, ymin = lower.CL, ymax = upper.CL)) + 
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  labs(x = 'Year', y = 'Distance (CI)')
```

[image]

Comment: @ Axeman,  many thanks for your prompt reply and help.  is it possible to plot these as shown in pic above. thank you

Comment: If you made it an ordered factor, would you be able to estimate a “trend” effect.

Comment: @IRTFM, many thanks, could you please help how can i make order factor to estimate trend effect.

Comment: @Axeman, thank you so much. that really helpfull. what arugment i can add so i can see 95% CI in : em <- emmeans(m1, ~ qun | year)
contrast(em, method = 'trt.vs.ctrl', ref = 'low')

Comment: Ordered factors should be described on the ?factor page. My question was to Axeman in hopes of learning whether there would be the option of constraining the estimates to only be “linear” since R regression functions usually calculate higher orders of polynomial contrasts by default. The hacky way to get a linear (trend) contrast is to use integers 0:2. You would only get a single estimate.